# Align the icon and the textbox in the same line even when the screen is minimized using bootstrap

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap

Please let me know how to align the textbox and icon with label in the same line.
I have researched on this. all the answers will work if the screen is in full size.If the browser is minimized the icon will shift to next line.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="margin-left:1px;">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label"><span class="mandatory">* </span>label: </label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <select class="form-control " ng-model="es" required>
                        <option value="" selected> -- Select One --</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <img nng-click="open();" ng-src="../../Content/images/info1.png"  />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Let me know if one has idea. I am new to these styles.

Comment: You can float left the label tag.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using bootstrap: there is a form-horizontal for that.
or just use this (if you don't care about IE9 :-) ):

```
.row .form-group {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 2;
}

.row .form-group label {
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Comment: display:flex worked to make this icon align on the same line, but all the labels and textboxes are now float to left when the screen is minimized without proper gap between the label and textboxes like when the screen is in full size

Comment: can you provide a Fiddle for this issue or do you have any link?

Comment: Please find the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KZA1Nu8JuQ9cdH592vdh?p=preview. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I updated my answer! I hope I understood what you want. You can add flex-wrap: wrap if you want that the input fields brake to new line when the viewport is too small. I think you need a min-width of your body (i.e. 320px) and under this width nothing should brake. Just play around with the flex properties but this should done the thing